# iOS GoogleMaps area accuracy and Polygon drawing

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-location

I am trying to mark location points while walking around small area say my house. How accurate it would be to draw perimeter i.e. Polygon. 
How accurate the distance would be. 
Thirdly can we draw curved path
Any suggestion with experience will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the accuracy of the polygon area, but there's a lot of questions about it when searched (eg. [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037083/calculating-area-of-a-polygon-drawn-on-google-map).

For drawing curved path, you can use the `GMSPolyline` with `geodesic` option set to `YES`.

> When YES, render this polyline edge as a geodesic. Geodesic segments follow the shortest path along the Earth's surface and may appear as curved lines on a map with a Mercator projection. Non-geodesic segments are drawn as straight lines on the map. Defaults to NO.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Just wondering how accurate it would be to walk around house and mark points. ?

Comment: I'm presuming it would be fairly accurate, having the [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) would help have accurate location.